# Limiting word count in tags

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The project I'm currently working on is a professional networking site running on BuddyPress/Wordpress. One of the features we added to everyone's profile is a text area for tags, e.g. professional interests and personal interests. The users are instructed to keep their tags to 1-3 words and separate them with a comma (e.g. "mountain biking, wine, crocheting"). However, we have some $&%^@# stupid users who think the area is meant for writing essays, such as "I like dressing up my cats and dancing naked to Motley Crue records while seaching for travel deals on Kayak," rather than just writing "cats, Motley Crue, traveling." [Headslap.]

Despite putting in clear instructions on what a tag is and isn't, users are still ignorant. We've decided to try restricting the users' input words. Is there a good way to check a string that's delimited by commas, and then put up a popup or other warning saying, "Hey, dummy, tags can't be more than 3 words long!"? I've found a few javascript blurbs that allow for character limits, but nothing that will take the input apart and count the words between commas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Put the string into an array and then count how many occurences.

`$interests = explode(",", $_POST['interests']);

$total = count($interests);`

[explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will separate the textarea string into an array.  You can then count how many elements are in the array and slap heads as needed!

Comment: I think you wanted to use `explode` here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.split()` method in JS, like so:

```
var str = "My really long annoying tag, my tag, good tag, lol";
var tags = str.split(",");
for(var tag in tags) {
    if(tags[tag].split(" ").length > 3) {
       alert("HEY DUMMY, '" + tags[tag] + "' is too long!!");
    } 

}
```